# com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException:

Tags: jsf

I created a Java EE web application with JSF 2 (PrimeFaces), Hibernate and Spring. I added all necessary jars and I declared my beans in `faces-config`.

When I run my application I get the following exception:

---

```
enter code here

An Error Occurred:
Erreur lors de l’injection de ressources dans le bean géré «loginBean»
+- Stack Trace
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Erreur lors de l’injection de     
ressources dans le bean géré «loginBean»
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:229)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
at 
 com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
at 
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at 
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
at 
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:64)
at 

org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup
(InputTextRenderer.java:77)
at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd
(InputTextRenderer.java:51)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive
(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren
(GridRenderer.java:129)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent
(PanelRenderer.java:202)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup
(PanelRenderer.java:119)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:56)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView
(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView
(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute
(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke
(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke
(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke
(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke
(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process
(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException
at   com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod
 (WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct
(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct
(BeanBuilder.java:223)
... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod
(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:117)
... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.plasticum.beans.LoginBean.init(LoginBean.java:29)
... 63 more

+ - Component Tree
<UIViewRoot id="j_id1" inView="true" locale="fr_FR" renderKitId="HTML_BASIC"     
rendered="true" transient="false" viewId="/pages/loginx.xhtml">
javax_faces_location_HEAD
<ComponentResourceContainer id="javax_faces_location_HEAD" inView="true"    
rendered="true" transient="false">
<UIOutput inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"/>
<UIOutput inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"/>
<UIOutput inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"/>
<UIOutput inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"/>
<UIOutput inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"/>
<UIOutput inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"/>
</ComponentResourceContainer>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"   
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib">
<UIOutput id="j_idt3" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">
<title>Authentification</title> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    
href="../css/styles.css"/>
</UIOutput>
<UIOutput id="j_idt5" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">
<center>
<HtmlForm enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="form" inView="true"   
prependId="true" rendered="true" submitted="false" transient="false">
<Panel closable="false" closeSpeed="500" collapsed="false" header="Authentification"   
id="panel" inView="true" rendered="true" toggleOrientation="vertical" toggleSpeed="500" 
toggleable="false" transient="false" visible="true">
<Messages autoUpdate="false" closable="false" escape="true" globalOnly="false"   
id="msgs" inView="true" redisplay="true" rendered="true" showDetail="false" 
showSummary="true" transient="false"/>
<Clock autoSync="false" id="j_idt7" inView="true" mode="server" pattern="HH:mm:ss   
dd.MM.yyyy" rendered="true" syncInterval="60000" transient="false"/>
<HtmlPanelGrid border="-2147483648" columns="3" id="j_idt8" inView="true"   
rendered="true" 
transient="false">
<HtmlOutputLabel escape="true" for="identifiant" id="j_idt9" inView="true"    
rendered="true" transient="false" value="Identifiant "/>
<InputText disabled="false" id="identifiant" immediate="false" inView="true"    
label="Identifiant" localValueSet="false" maxlength="-2147483648" readonly="false" 
rendered="true" required="true" size="-2147483648" transient="false" type="text"    
valid="true"/>
<Message display="icon" escape="true" for="identifiant" id="j_idt10" inView="true"    
redisplay="true" rendered="true" showDetail="true" showSummary="false"   
transient="false"/>
<HtmlOutputLabel escape="true" id="j_idt11" inView="true" rendered="true"    
transient="false" value="Mot de passe"/>
<Password disabled="false" feedback="false" goodLabel="Good" id="mp" immediate="false"   
inView="true" inline="false" label="mot de passe" localValueSet="false" 
maxlength="-2147483648" promptLabel="Please enter a password" readonly="false"   
redisplay="false" rendered="true" required="true" size="-2147483648"    
strongLabel="Strong" 
transient="false" valid="true" weakLabel="Weak"/>
<Message display="icon" escape="true" for="mp" id="msgSurname" inView="true"    
redisplay="true" rendered="true" showDetail="true" showSummary="false"    
transient="false"/>  
</HtmlPanelGrid>
<CommandButton action="#{loginBean.connect()}" actionExpression="#   
{loginBean.connect()}" ajax="true" async="false" disabled="false" escape="true" 
global="true" iconPos="left" id="btn" immediate="false" inView="true" inline="false" 
partialSubmit="false" readonly="false" rendered="true" transient="false" type="submit"
update="panel" value="Valider"/>
</Panel>
</HtmlForm>
</center>
</UIOutput>
</html>
</UIViewRoot>
+- Scoped Variables
Request Parameters Name Value 
None 
View Attributes Name Value 
None 
Request Attributes Name Value 
None 
Flash Attributes Name Value 
None 
Session Attributes Name Value 
None 
Application Attributes Name Value 
csfcff com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash@1c8a2ab
```

Comment: No code. And there's a very clear `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` in your stack trace. What version of JSF is this btw?

Answer (score 1):

i think that i resolved this probleme by adding all nessesary annotation for my managed bean like @managedbaen and @managedproperty, but now i have an other exception that i can't inderstand this is my logonbean :

```
package com.plasticum.beans;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.plasticum.service.UtilisateurService;
import com.plasticum.web.UtilisateurBean;
import com.plasticum.model.*;


@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "utlisateurService")
//@ViewScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {


@ManagedProperty(value="#{UtilisateurService}")
UtilisateurService utilisateurservice;
private String login;
private String password;

List<Utilisateur> list= utilisateurservice.findall();

/*@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    UtilisateurBean utilisateurbean = new UtilisateurBean();
    list = utilisateurbean.getList();
}*/

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String connect() {

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    /*for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getNom().equals(login)
                && list.get(i).getMp().equals(password)) {
            return "menu";
        }
    }*/
        String hh=list.get(1).getNom();
    fc.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(hh));
    return "login";
    /*
     * FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     * if(login.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")){return"menu";}
     * else{
     * 
     * fc.addMessage(null, new
     * FacesMessage("login ou mot de passe incorrect  !!!!"));
     * return"login";}
     */
    /*
     * String log=""; String pass=""; FacesContext
     * fc=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
     * { log=list.get(i).getNom(); //+" "+list.get(i).getPrenom();
     * pass=list.get(i).getMp(); if(this.login.equals(log) &&
     * this.password.equals(pass)){return "menu";}
     * 
     * } fc.addMessage(null, new
     * FacesMessage("login ou mot de passe incorrect  !!!!"));
     * return"login";
     */
}

public java.util.List getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(java.util.List list) {
    this.list = list;
}
public UtilisateurService getUtilisateurservice() {
    return utilisateurservice;
}

public void setUtilisateurservice(UtilisateurService utilisateurservice) {
    this.utilisateurservice = utilisateurservice;
}
}
```

and this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
     xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>plasticum</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>

<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
<param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
<param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
<param-value>bluesky</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-  
class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-
class>  
</listener>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath:application_context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
<param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>


<context-param>
<description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF  
Specification 2.5.2</description>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
<param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>


</web-app>
```

and this my application context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
<bean id="utilisateurService" class="com.plasticum.service.UtilisateurServiceImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="RebutService" class="com.plasticum.service.RebutServiceImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="McService" class="com.plasticum.service.McServiceImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="MccService" class="com.plasticum.service.MccServiceImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="HistoriqueService" class="com.plasticum.service.HistoriqueServiceImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="DescDefService" class="com.plasticum.service.DescDefServiceImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="DefautService" class="com.plasticum.service.DefautServiceImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="CritereService" class="com.plasticum.service.CritereServiceImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="ArticleService" class="com.plasticum.service.ArticleServiceImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.plasticum.service" />
<bean id='dataSource' class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/plasticum" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
<bean id="SessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.plasticum.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop 
key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="SessionFactory">
</bean>

</beans>
```

this is my login.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" 
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib">
<h:head>
<title>Authentification </title>

</h:head>
<h:body>

 <center> 
   <h:form id="form">  
      <p:panel id="panel" header="Authentification">  
       <p:messages id="msgs"/>  

         <h:panelGrid columns="3">  
           <h:outputLabel  for="identifiant" value="Identifiant " />  
            <p:inputText id="identifiant" value="#{loginBean.login}" required="true"   
label="Identifiant">  
             <f:validateLength minimum="2" />  
           </p:inputText>  
           <p:message for="identifiant" display="icon"/>  


          <h:outputLabel  value="Mot de passe" />  
          <p:password id="mp" value="#{loginBean.password}" label="mot de passe" 
required="true">  
           <f:validateLength minimum="2" />  
           <p:ajax update="mp" event="keyup" />  
         </p:password>  
        <p:message for="mp" id="msgSurname" display="icon"/>  

       </h:panelGrid>  

    <p:commandButton id="btn" value="Valider" update="panel" action="#  
{loginBean.connect()}"/>  
</p:panel>  

</h:form>  



  </center> 







</h:body>

 </html>
```